# Graphql without a server

Tags: graphql-dotnet

I'd like to include an embedded graphql processor in my .net app.

I want to execute GraphQL functions via a method and I don't need the server or an endpoint.

Basically an internal GraphQL processor. I'll define the resolvers and the schema and then run queries via a method call. Is this possible?

Comment: For software recommendations, the right place is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. The word you are looking for is "client". Look for a GraphQL client. First search result on GGL: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client

Comment: I don't think client is quite what I need. I need server functionality, but via a method rather then an endpoint. Doesn't a client just call the server?

Comment: Then you need a server and a client in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look [NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql/) (which is based on GraphQL.Net but has an additional features, like aggregation, filter, ect.). You can compose in code schema, query (or query object) and call it just in-code.